# Can't drop and recreate FK in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, corruption, dbcc

I have a DBCC check that will always fail with the following error:

> Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Check Catalog
>
> Msg 3853, State 1:
> Attribute (referenced_object_id=517752334,key_index_id=1) of row (object_id=660509732) in sys.foreign_keys does not have a matching row (object_id=517752334,index_id=1) in sys.indexes.

I have found the problem where the `referenced_object_id` is wrong and needs to be changed to 517785102 for `FK_SytModuleStat_SytModule`.

I can't change it in `sys.foreign_keys` and I can't drop and recreate the `FK_SytModuleStat_SytModule` in the `SytModuleStat` to fix the problem. The only problem is that the FK is no longer correct when I try to modify it, I see that the primary/unique key base and column fields are blank compared to a working one.

I have tried many suggestions with alter, drop create, set emergency etc. But I can't fix this one key!

I have tried to connect with DAC in single user mode and it won't let me enable ad hoc updates even with the reconfigure overrride option. I get this error:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

DBCC repair with data loss won't work, and there doesn't seem to be a repair catalog feature in SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user tables are readable, use the [Copy Database Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16) selecting the "SQL Management Object method" to copy your objects to a new database.  After verifying the data and security in the new databases, backup and drop the old one and rename the new one.